# mysql query to find overlap in joined tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have 2 tables; profiles & invoices.
profiles is the main table which has all my people in it.
then some of these people have invoices (individuals can have none, one or more than one invoice). the invoice table has a field 'profileid' which links it to the relevant id in profiles.
the invoice table has a field named 'paid' which says either 'Paid' or 'Unpaid'.

hope thats clear

now I have a search page where one can search all the profiles.
I have 2 checkboxes so you can filter all those that have an invoices paid and all those that have unpaid invoices.

it works fine individually but not together. ie, if you tick box for invoices paid it gives you all profiles who have ever paid an invoice, and if you tick unpaid it gives you all people with unpaid invoices; but if you tick both boxes it gives you 0 results, when it should give you all the people who both have unpaid and paid invoices.

here is my count query:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profiles.id) AS num FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid) 
AND (invoices.paid='Paid' OR invoices.paid='Unpaid')
WHERE
(
IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE '$paid%' 
AND IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE '$unpaid%' 
);
```

spent ages on this and can't get it to work, any help is much appreciated.
thanks

Comment: Just curious (maybe I misread)... Why are you asking it for a `COUNT`? And is it giving you more than one result each time?

Answer (score 1):

Its checking if its paid `AND` unpaid at the same time. Obviously it can never be both!

You will have to use `OR` or just skip this check in case both options are selected.

Comment: hmm. i've tried with OR and it gives me the exact same results

Comment: The query you are working only gives you the count of results, not the results properly. Perhaps there is more than one place you should be checking.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT profiles.id) AS num FROM profiles 
LEFT JOIN invoices ON (profiles.id=invoices.profileid) 
AND (invoices.paid='Paid' OR invoices.paid='Unpaid')
WHERE
IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE '$paid%' 
OR IFNULL(invoices.paid, '') LIKE '$unpaid%'
```

But a whole different thing is that you shouldn't use interpolated variables (like `$paid` above) and I find it odd that you have to use `LIKE '[...]%'` to select the right value. It looks as if the database schema is in a bad shape.

Comment: thanks, but with OR it gives me the exact same results. also what do you mean by interpolated variables?

Comment: What are the values of ``$paid`` and ``$unpaid`` when you do the call that doesn't return any rows? In other words, let's reduce this to a pure SQL problem.

Comment: $paid would = 'Paid' and $unpaid would = 'Unpaid'

Comment: but i've been playing about with it a bit more now. it does need to be AND because i need all the profiles with invoice Paid AND Unpaid - the problem lies with the DISTINCT - its filtering out all duplicate profiles after the tables are joined, and thats what im trying to search - if that makes sense

Comment: Okay. It sounds as if you're solving the issue yourself.